# transpose dict of lists and write to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write a dict of lists to a tsv file. The problem is that I'm not able to **transpose** the lists.

I have the following dict of lists:

> print d

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['Genemark1.10973_g', 'missense_variant', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_100', 305, '605', 'Asp', 'Gly', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 2: ['estExt_Genewise1Plus.C_1000001', 'disruptive_inframe_insertion', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_100', 5002, '7172', 'Gly', '', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 3: ['fgenesh2_pm.100_#_3', 'inframe_insertion', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_100', 10104, '265266', 'Leu', '', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 4: ['estExt_fgenesh2_pg.C_100178', 'inframe_deletion', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_10', 711411, '351352', 'Gln', '', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 5: ['estExt_fgenesh2_pm.C_1060001', 'disruptive_inframe_deletion', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_106', 5189, '832', 'Leu', 'del', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 6: ['Genemark1.10980_g', 'frameshift_variant', 'HIGH', 'scaffold_101', 10838, '313', 'Leu', 'fs', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO'], 7: ['Genemark1.10973_g', 'missense_variant', 'MODERATE', 'scaffold_100', 2043, '26', 'Ile', 'Leu', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'], 8: ['fgenesh2_pm.104_#_2', 'stop_gained', 'HIGH', 'scaffold_104', 8574, '310', 'Tyr', '*', 'YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO']})
```

This is my function:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
    def printAnn(d):
        rows = izip_longest(*d.values())
        w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n')
        w.writerows(rows)
```

The output I'm getting:

```
Genemark1.10973_g   estExt_Genewise1Plus.C_1000001  fgenesh2_pm.100_#_3 estExt_fgenesh2_pg.C_100178 estExt_fgenesh2_pm.C_1060001    Genemark1.10980_g   Genemark1.10973_g   fgenesh2_pm.104_#_2
missense_variant    disruptive_inframe_insertion    inframe_insertion   inframe_deletion    disruptive_inframe_deletion frameshift_variant  missense_variant    stop_gained
MODERATE    MODERATE    MODERATE    MODERATE    MODERATE    HIGH    MODERATE    HIGH
scaffold_100    scaffold_100    scaffold_100    scaffold_10 scaffold_106    scaffold_101    scaffold_100    scaffold_104
305 5002    10104   711411  5189    10838   2043    8574
605 7172    265266  351352  832 313 26  310
Asp Gly Leu Gln Leu Leu Ile Tyr
Gly             del fs  Leu *
YES YES YES YES YES NO  YES YES
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  YES NO  NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO  NO
```

**PS**: I've tried `izip_longest` with a single list (not dict of lists) and it worked fine. What I'm missing?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: So what is your expected output? You want each list as a row in your csv?

Comment: What I want is: the first element of each list should occupy the first column, the second element the second column... at the end I expect to have a table with as much rows as lists, and as much cols as elemetns in the largest list. So, basically is the transpose of the output that I am getting. I am preparing the expected output to clarify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to `zip` for your requirement. Think about it. You want each element of a row to appear in its column, which is same as just keeping the row intact.

```
def printAnn(d):
    w = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, lineterminator='\n')
    w.writerows(d.values())

printAnn(d)
Genemark1.10973_g       missense_variant        MODERATE        scaffold_100 305     605     Asp     Gly     YES     NO      NO      NO
estExt_Genewise1Plus.C_1000001  disruptive_inframe_insertion    MODERATE scaffold_100    5002    7172    Gly             YES     NO      NO      NO
fgenesh2_pm.100_#_3     inframe_insertion       MODERATE        scaffold_100 10104   265266  Leu             YES     NO      NO      NO
estExt_fgenesh2_pg.C_100178     inframe_deletion        MODERATE       scaffold_10     711411  351352  Gln             YES     NO      NO      NO
estExt_fgenesh2_pm.C_1060001    disruptive_inframe_deletion     MODERATE scaffold_106    5189    832     Leu     del     YES     NO      NO      NO
Genemark1.10980_g       frameshift_variant      HIGH    scaffold_101    10838 313     Leu     fs      NO      YES     NO      NO
Genemark1.10973_g       missense_variant        MODERATE        scaffold_100 2043    26      Ile     Leu     YES     NO      NO      NO
fgenesh2_pm.104_#_2     stop_gained     HIGH    scaffold_104    8574    310 Tyr     *       YES     NO      NO      NO
```

If this is not what you wanted please comment.

Comment: OMG.  I thought the opposite. Too many hours working. Thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @cucurbit don't freak out. It's completely all right to err. It's integral to writing imperative code. :)